# Scalar Multiplication in Sage?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, sage

I have a file named test1.sage:

```
  test1.sage:    
      M = Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
      R = 1/2*M
      print R
      print M

%run test1.sage
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]

[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
```

When I run the .sage file its giving me this random zero matrix. But, line-by-line, in the sage shell, it works perfectly fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that in Python (2.x) `1/2` gives zero.   This is (was) a long standard, and certainly isn't the only language that does this.

If you run the file *with Sage* you should be fine.

```
$ sage test1.sage 
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[1/2   1 3/2]
[  2 5/2   3]
```

The comments indicate that `%run` must be an IPython "magic" function.  My guess is that it isn't changed in Sage to make it a *Sage* magic function, and the following confirms it:

Make a file containing just `print 1/2`.  Do `sage test1.sage` to get the `test1.py` file in your directory.  Then run Sage and do this:

```
sage: %run test1.sage
0
sage: %run test1.py
1/2
```

I've opened [Trac 15891](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15891) for this, thanks!

Comment: I did mean R and M. Fixed it now. 
%run is used within the sage shell to run files. But I still have no idea why it turns the matrix to all 0s. I'm thinking this could be a bug..

Comment: Also why would my Python 2.6 take 1/2 as zero?

Comment: Dividing integers is defined that way. Access the remainder with %. Seems you run IPython and this uses python2.